# How do you put two characters in a while loop in C?

Tags: c, input, while-loop, char, repeat

How do you put two characters in a while loop in C, for the two* to be identified only when required?

```
    char inputChar = '\n';

    printf("Type of Pizza:\n");
    printf(" Vegetarian (v) or Non-vegetarian (nv) ?\n\t ");
    scanf("%c", &inputChar);

    while (inputChar != 'v' && inputChar != 'nv') {
        printf("\n>>>\t Invalid choice   . Try again  <<<<<.\n");
        printf("\n Vegetarian (v) or Non-vegetarian (nv) ?\n\t ");
        scanf("%c", &inputChar);
    }

    printf("%c", inputChar);
    if ('v') {
        printf("\t ... vegetarian\n");
    }
    else {
        if ('nv') {printf("\t ... non-vegetarian\n"); }
    }
```

I want the code to identify the v & nv but it only identifies the v and it keeps printing:

```
    printf("\n>>>\t Invalid choice   . Try again  <<<<<.\n");
    printf("\n Vegetarian (v) or Non-vegetarian (nv) ?\n\t ");
```

twice before providing a space for your input.

Comment: ``if ('v')`` is the same as ``if (true)`` or ``if (1)``. It never changes.

Comment: `nv` is _two_ characters. You want to read a _string_ from the user, and use `strcmp` to compare it to `"v"` and `"nv"`. EDIT: btw, you should turn up your compiler warnings: `'nv'` is a multi-char constant which doesn’t mean what it looks like, and should get you a warning about using it.

Comment: @HERO_FIIFI Use scanf(" %c", &inputChar); instead of scanf("%c", &inputChar); (see a space before the conversion specifier %c.)

Comment: You want to input a string which may contain one or two characters.  You should therefore use `char inputStr[10]; … if (scanf("%9s", inputStr) != 1) { …read problem… }` and then use `if (strcmp(inputStr, "v") == 0) { …vegetarian… } else if (strcmp(inputStr, "nv") == 0) { …non-vegetarian… } else { printf("Unrecognized input '%s' - try again\n", inputStr); }`.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifications

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You want to turn that into an answer? (If not, I can.)

Comment: @Dúthomhas — your wish is my command (in this rather limited context).

Answer (score 2):

You want to input a string which may contain one or two characters. You should therefore use something like:

```c
char inputStr[10];
…
if (scanf("%9s", inputStr) != 1)
{
    …read problem…
    …abandon program?…
}
…
if (strcmp(inputStr, "v") == 0)
{
    …vegetarian…
}
else if (strcmp(inputStr, "nv") == 0)
{
    …non-vegetarian…
}
else
{
    printf("Unrecognized input '%s' - try again\n", inputStr);
}
```

Note that the input allows for more than 2 characters, but people are apt to type things you didn't expect them to type.  Specifying `%9s` prevents buffer overflows.  String comparison is done with `strcmp()` from `<string.h>`.  If you want the input to be case-insensitive, use the tools from `#include <ctype.h>` to case-convert the input to lower-case.  Using `"%c"` for single character input is fraught because unlike most conversion specifications (such as `%s`), it doesn't skip white space.  Typically, using `" %c"` with a space before `%c` is better; it skips over (optional) white space, such as the newline left behind by the previous input, before reading a character that isn't white space.